# AutoFilter to exclude specific value using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

[image: spreadsheet example]

I want to AutoFilter column B to filter out the rows with favourite colour as red.

I've managed to automate it as follows and it works fine:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$B$8").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=_
"=BLUE", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="YELLOW", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria3:=_
"=PURPLE", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria4:="WHITE"
```

I have 4 criteria's. I was wondering if it's possible to use only one criteria that filters out the colour red instead?

Comment: If you record a macro while filtering out the red, it will show you the syntax required: `Criteria1:="<>RED`"

Comment: Your provided code does not actually work fine.

Comment: @Joe J Thanks man, all sorted!

Comment: @BigBen I may have made some errors in copying the code. i noticed i left out some quotation marks when stating my range. i've sorted it now.

Comment: But you really haven't, right? See the [`Range.AutoFilter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.autofilter) docs why - it only supports 2 criteria. `Operator:=xlOr, Criteria3:=_
"=PURPLE", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria4:="WHITE"` is all invalid.

Comment: *2 criteria parameters. One can pass an array of criteria as explained in the same docs.